# Wait until assets being loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, tone.js

I have an application here https://maliyshock.github.io/simon-says/
For this app, I am using this library https://tonejs.github.io
I need to be sure that all of the sounds where downloaded successfully. before to run the application.

In my mind, in future updates, it will become a guitar hero, but with a dubstep. :D 
I am going to create music phrases with different sounds, rhythms, and duration. The main feature of this is replayability. Cause each song would be generated from the bank of phrases.

In redux/react stack we should update the state of the application by dispatching the actions, to say to reducer what to do.

The problem is, that I need to download all the sounds before the game starts. And the only way I see is to make it inside of the reducer. But it seems wrong to me.

```
const initialWordsState = {
    dictionary: [
        {
            ALFA: {
                color: {
                    name: 'blue',
                    value: BLUE
                },
                sound: new Tone.Player({ "url": alfa_sound, 'onload': ()=>{} }).toMaster(),
                active: false
            }
        },
        {
            OMEGA: {
                color: {
                    name: 'orange',
                    value: ORANGE
                },
                sound: new Tone.Player({ "url": omega_sound, 'onload': ()=>{} }).toMaster(),
                active: false
            },
        },
        {
            BETHA: {
                color: {
                    name: 'red',
                    value: RED
                },
                sound: new Tone.Player({ "url": betha_sound, 'onload': ()=>{} }).toMaster(),
                active: false
            },
        },
        {
            THETHA: {
                color: {
                    name: 'green',
                    value: GREEN
                },
                sound: new Tone.Player({ "url": thetha_sound, 'onload': ()=>{} }).toMaster(),
                active: false
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

As you can see, each button has a sound. In the future, each button will have multiple sounds regarding the phrase and the sound duration.

I am not sure how to do that. The only thing that comes to my mind is to use `onload` callback from the `Tone.player` to update the store and check it with a tick while all the sounds have been downloaded. In case all of them have been downloaded - show proper screen. 
But it seems to me it is wrong to do it like that.

Comment: It's not a standard to wait assets load to launch a web app, but in case it's gamified then I guess that would be ok. would you like to something like this: Loading screen shows until the Assets You Desire are fully Loaded, then replace the Loading screen with the main content of your game?

Comment: Sure 100% work for me. The problem is, how would I get this event in my app?